# cocoa app exit code wont execute even if i had sleep thread

Tags: swift, cocoa

i'm trying to save the peferences on my application on app exit
but the code wont run
i tried diff code and same result

```
func applicationShouldTerminate(_ sender: NSApplication) -> NSApplication.TerminateReply {
    //   print(arrayOfUsernamesList)
    UserDefaults.standard.setValue("prefs1", forKey: "preferences")
    return .terminateNow
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's the wrong delegate method, use `applicationWillTerminate`.

And **never** use `setValue(_:forKey` to save something to `UserDefaults`. Use always the generic `set(_:forKey`

```
func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification)
{
    UserDefaults.standard.set("prefs1", forKey: "preferences")
}
```

Comment: @MohmmadS `setValue` is a key-value coding method with a special functionality and overhead. Use KVC methods only if you really need KVC (never in this case).

Comment: when i use  exit(0) to close the application it doesnt call that function is there anyway to close the app other than exit(o) ext?

Comment: Why `exit(0)`? That's for CLIs. The usual way is `NSApp.terminate(nil)` which calls the delegate method.